# Use Fluent syntax to suffix index with "WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON) ON [PRIMARY];"

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to specify that the index is suffixed with

"WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON) ON [PRIMARY];"

when the SQL is created?

Hoping for something like ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeTable>()
.HasIndex(c => c.SomeField)
.IsClustered(false)
.SortInTempDB();  <- made up, but hoping for something like this :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not at this current point in time 15/08/2023. However there is an open issue and PR, which you can follow here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30408